# Can I leave an Aloe plant unattended for 2 months?

Tags: containers, succulents, perennials, aloe

I leave my apartment for 2 months and I'd like to know if you have any advice to keep my Aloe alive all this time?

I live near the Mediterranean and my balcony is exposed to the sun **from 1:30 pm to sunset.**

[image]

Here you can see the size of my Aloe vera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have over 400 Aloe plants. A couple of them are Aloe vera. They have to be inside for 5 months of the year due to freezing temperatures. During that time I do not water them. Over the summer, they are outdoors, and get some rain water so I don't water them there. If you grow them in a soil base mix Aloes thrive with a lot of minerals available, and a neutral-alkaline pH), they can easily handle periods of little to no moisture.

I'd say, just give it a good water before you go, and that cloth over the pot is a good idea, to help keep it from drying.

Here's a picture of my largest one (in an 8 gallon pot) from March 5 this year (after 4 months of no water), indoors:

[image]

Here's a pic from April 14 (the day it got outdoors):

[image]

As you can guess, my point here is that Aloes do not really need as much attention as people assume Especially water-wise, when they're not getting a full day of sun.

Comment: I could definitely see our aloe surviving a couple months without water, but it might appreciate water at least monthly, or so. The soil probably matters a lot, though, including how much soil there is.

Answer (score 4):

Best chance for your plant to survive your leave, is to ask a neighbor to water it every other week. Or ask a friend or neighbor to take it in their house for two months.

I think your plant won't survive two months without water, especially not with spring/summer conditions.